# How to catch update exception and what kind of notification to do here?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, exception, try-catch

I have a trigger with helper class and test. But I don't know how to test update there and what kind of notification I need. Thanks for any help.

Trigger:

```
trigger ArchivedTrigger on Item__c (after update) {
JTriggerHelper triggerHelper = new TriggerHelper();

if(Trigger.isUpdate){ 
    for(Item__c item : Trigger.new){
        if(item.Status__c == 'Old'){
            triggerHelper.remove(item);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Helper:

```
public void remove(Item__c item){
    List<Tool__c> toolsList  = [SELECT Id, CustomIDs__c FROM Tool__c];

    for(Tool__c tool : toolsList){
        if(tool.CustomIDs__c != null && tool.CustomIDs__c.contains(item.CustomIDs__c)){
            List<String> positionIdsList = String.valueOf(tool.CustomIDs__c).split(' ');

            for(Integer i=0; i<positionIdsList.size(); i++){
                if(positionIdsList[i] == item.CustomIDs__c){
                    positionIdsList.remove(i);   
                } 
            }
            tool.CustomIDs__c = String.join(positionIdsList,' ');

            try{
                update tool;
            //How to test an exception here?
            } catch(Exception e){
                //What is better to do here? Email? Logs for developer?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@isTest
static void testUpdateTrigger() {
    TriggerHelper triggerHelper = new TriggerHelper();

    Tool__c tool = new Tool__c(Email__c = 'test@test.com', CustomIDs__c = 'text 999999');
    insert tool;
    Item__c testTool = new Item__c(CustomIDs__c = '999999');
    insert testTool;

    testTool.Status__c = 'Old';
    update testTool;

    Test.startTest();
        triggerHelper.removePositionId(testTool);
    Test.stopTest();

    Tool__c toolTest = [SELECT CustomIDs__c FROM Tool__c WHERE Email__c = 'test@test.com'];
    System.assertEquals('text', toolTest.CustomIDs__c);
}
```

Comment: I think that you have several things in your code that are not very going to work well. For loops inside for loops is not a good practice. DML operations inside loops, issues as well. Problems as reaching governor limits quite fast. Can you please elaborate a bit more on the requirements so we can help you with it? I think you should get your trigger working properly before jumping to the test class. You could also start writing your  test class first , but the is an other approach.Tell us what it is that you want to accomplish and the data model involved in this business case.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you don't need to do this in after update, as you are just populating `tool.CustomIDs__c` field. You can do the same in `before update` trigger and no need to update records explicitly.

Second, you are trying to update single record at a time in a for loop which is not recommended, every DML must be bulkified, I would suggest you to learn in detail about apex triggers [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro)

after modification your code be like

Trigger

```
trigger ArchivedTrigger on Item__c (before update) {
    JTriggerHelper triggerHelper = new TriggerHelper();

    if(Trigger.isUpdate){ 
        for(Item__c item : Trigger.new){
            if(item.Status__c == 'Old'){
                triggerHelper.remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Helper:

```
public void remove(Item__c item){
    List<Tool__c> toolsList  = [SELECT Id, CustomIDs__c FROM Tool__c];

    for(Tool__c tool : toolsList){
        if(tool.CustomIDs__c != null && tool.CustomIDs__c.contains(item.CustomIDs__c)){
            List<String> positionIdsList = String.valueOf(tool.CustomIDs__c).split(' ');

            for(Integer i=0; i<positionIdsList.size(); i++){
                if(positionIdsList[i] == item.CustomIDs__c){
                    positionIdsList.remove(i);   
                } 
            }
            tool.CustomIDs__c = String.join(positionIdsList,' ');

            /* no need to update as in before trigger any changes made in trigger context records will be saved in database
            */
        }
    }
}
```